# Problems with python and paramiko stat returning on non existing file

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, stat

Code:

```
try:    
    ajoLogi.ajoLogi("Onko tiedosto "+dst+" jo palvelimella", "Stat")
    stat = sftpClient.stat(dst)
    print(stat)
    if stat.st_mtime != 0 :
        leima = datetime.fromtimestamp(stat.st_mtime)                    
        ajoLogi.ajoLogi("Tiedoston aikaleima:"+leima.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "Stat")
    else :
        ajoLogi.ajoLogi("Tiedoston aikaleima on nolla", "Stat")
        continue
```

Result:

```
drwx------   1 0        0               0 01 Jan 1980  ?
```

*File doesn't exist on the destination sftp-server - the expected result is an exception.*

Same piece of code works with my test server as expected, an exception is thrown. Also stat returns same bleak results for existing files. The original files have been transported to the destination sftp server by the same user id and the same script.

**Any idea what is happening here and how I can work around it?**

I don't have any other access to the target server than the low access sftp-account used. Trying the same account with manual sftp command shows that file is not there and allows putting and deleting the file just fine.

**Partial solution**

The server that caused the problems was : "SSH-2.0-6.4.10.264 SSH Tectia Server" which required all paths to be absolute - that is to begin with '/'. Without that everything fails.

With "SSH-2.0-6.4.7.204 SSH Tectia Server", the server I tested against, server requires that all paths to be relative or everything fails.

What the latter does with absolute paths - according to Windows application log:

```
2016 Sft_server_stat_file_failed, "2016 Sft_server_stat_file_failed,
File  name: /7120/in/FPVI4170.ERI, "Error: Permission denied", 
Session-Id: 8745309"
```

and with relative paths:

```
2015 Sft_server_stat_file, "2015 Sft_server_stat_file, 
File name: \\xxxxx.yyyy.local\files\user.name\7120\in\FPVI4170.ERI,
"Success", Session-Id: 8745716"
```

When the path is not found, that you try to stat, then both server versions will return the same bogus stat information (see above).

I personally cheer for the helpful error message: "Permission denied" it is in the line with what the stat-command returns. It would be absolutely terrible if the event log would spoil the fun for hunting the actual reason for the failure.

Comment: *Trying the same account with manual sftp command shows that file is not there*: What does that mean? What commands do you use in the command-line SFTP to test if the file exists?

Comment: sftp> **put TulinJuuriSallalta.txt 7120/TulinJuuriSallalta.txt**
Uploading TulinJuuriSallalta.txt to /7120/TulinJuuriSallalta.txt
TulinJuuriSallalta.txt                        100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00    
sftp> **dir 7120/TulinJuuriSallalta.txt**
7120/TulinJuuriSallalta.txt             
sftp> **rm 7120/TulinJuuriSallalta.txt**
Removing /7120/TulinJuuriSallalta.txt
sftp> **dir 7120/TulinJuuriSallata.txt**
Can't ls: "/7120/TulinJuuriSallata.txt" not found
sftp> quit
__Proves that file can be put, deleted and doesn't exist__. The script operates with full paths, without leading "/".

Comment: OK, can you try some SFTP client that supports "stat" command or equivalent? For example WinSCP: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_stat + What is your SSH/SFTP server?

Comment: After finding out that the destination server is Tectia server and as we have a few  in-house. I tried against one. If you have a Tectia server without "home" for the sftp user it will stat non existent "/" happily instead the file you are trying to stat and will return what you see above. This is at least what the event log on the a server claimed it was doing.  My current guess is that the destination server is a cluster where one or more of the servers have the home for the user and majority do not see the home directory. I'm waiting confirmation from the target organization.

Comment: So it looks like a server-side problem. Did you try WinSCP to verify?

Comment: There was no cluster on the other side. It seems to be a feature with Tectia, Dir-command causes exception on paramiko but stat returns bogus data with bogus paths. These bogus paths show up in Tectia logs as "stats" to the "/"-directory.

Comment: Note that the SFTP protocol knows only absolute paths. There's no concept of a "working directory" in the SFTP.